# StartDate and EndDate Parameter based on which Date column is chosen in another dropdown parameter

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services

I want to be able to set up a report in SSRS where you can filter the results by one of 3 date columns available as dropdown parameter and enter Start Date & End Date as parameter2 & parameter3 as Date Pickers.

Currently I have the Date Picker parameters for Start Date and End Date but I'm struggling to add the DropDown parameter to the query as I'm new to SSRS so not sure how I should go I about it.

This is my current code:

```
SELECT

Column1,
Column2,
Column3,
DateColumn1,
DateColumn2,
DateColumn3

FROM Table

WHERE DateColumn1 BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

I want something like this:

```
SELECT

Column1,
Column2,
Column3,
DateColumn1,
DateColumn2,
DateColumn3

FROM Table

WHERE @DateType BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

Where in this case I want to expand the earlier DateColumn1 to 'DateType' parameter which would allow me to create a dropdown parameter so that I can select either one of DateColumn1/DateColumn2/DateColumn3 from the dropdown and the 'StartDate' & 'EndDate' would filter for whatever DateType was chosen from the dropdown options.

I'm not sure if I'm thinking about this in a wrong way from SQL query point of view or if there are better ways to achieve this.

Thanks and sorry if I have not been clear in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identifiers can't be parameterized in SQL, however you can use a simple combination of `AND` and `OR` to filter over different columns based on the `@DateType` parameter, like this:

```
SELECT
    Column1,
    Column2,
    Column3,
    DateColumn1,
    DateColumn2,
    DateColumn3
FROM Table
WHERE (@DateType = 1 AND DateColumn1 >= @StartDate AND DateColumn1 <= @EndDate)
OR (@DateType = 2 AND DateColumn2 >= @StartDate AND DateColumn2 <= @EndDate)
OR (@DateType = 3 AND DateColumn3 >= @StartDate AND DateColumn3 <= @EndDate)
```

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to create a computed column in your query and then test against that. Something like

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT
        Column1,
        Column2,
        Column3,
        DateColumn1,
        DateColumn2,
        DateColumn3,
        CASE @DateType
            WHEN 1 THEN DateColumn1
            WHEN 2 THEN DateColumn2
            WHEN 3 THEN DateColumn3
            ELSE NULL
        END AS CompareDate
      FROM Table) x
    WHERE x.CompareDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

You may not need the DateColumn*n* columns but I left them in there in case.

Comment: Thanks this works as well but I think the earlier answer was simpler for my purpose. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted